# Create it so I don't have to login to windows when I am connected to a certain wifi network?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, security, passwords

How can I make it so if I am connected to a certain wifi network that I don't have to type in a username and password into the computer. But when not connect it requires a username and password. I am referring to turning on the computer and login into windows. For example, when connected to my home network, I just want it to log me into windows without a password. But if I turn my laptop on at work, I want it to ask for a password. The way it knows my location should be based on the wifi network it is connect to. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Developers wanting to implement this should start by reading about the [Windows Interactive Logon Architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404303(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I will ask my colleges to look into it.

Comment: Unless you have a cert to verify the connection is who it says it is then its really poor security. Spoof the SSID and accept any key, laptop just opens itself up. You can purchase hardware proximity fobs for not crazy money.

Comment: @Linef4ult Alright Thanks. I will probably purchase the hardware proximity fobs